# Not able to fetch the value of DiskSpaceUtilization Metric from the Cloudwatch with AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get the Used Disk Space (Percent) for my EC2 instance from Cloudwatch with the help of a lambda function. It returns no value.

And when I try to specify the Filesystem and Mountpath it shows an error -

> Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in MetricDataQueries[0].MetricStat.Metric.Dimensions[0]: \"Filesystem\", must be one of: Name, Value",
>         "errorType": "ParamValidationError"

Here is the full code.

```
import boto3
import datetime


def lambda_handler(event, context):
   client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
   response = client.get_metric_data(

       MetricDataQueries=[
           {
               'Id': 'd1',
               'MetricStat': {
                   'Metric': {
                       'Namespace': 'cloudwatch',
                       'MetricName': 'DiskSpaceUtilization',
                       'Dimensions': [
                           {
                               'Name': 'InstanceId',
                               'Value': '*****************',
                               'Filesystem': '/****/****'
                           },
                       ]
                   },
                   'Period': 300,
                   'Stat': 'Maximum',
                   'Unit': 'Percent'
               },
               'ReturnData': True
           },
       ],
       StartTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=600),
       EndTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
       ScanBy='TimestampDescending',
       MaxDatapoints=60

   )
   return response
```

I expect the output as DiskSpaceUtilization - x%.

But currently the output is

```
  "MetricDataResults": [
    {
      "Id": "d1",
      "Label": "DiskSpaceUtilization",
      "Timestamps": [],
      "Values": [],
      "StatusCode": "Complete"
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem is a separate dimension, change this:

```
'Dimensions': [
    {
        'Name': 'InstanceId',
        'Value': '*****************',
        'Filesystem': '/****/****'
    },
]
```

to this:

```
'Dimensions': [
    {
        'Name': 'InstanceId',
        'Value': '*****************'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'Filesystem',
        'Value': '/****/****'
    }
]
```

and see what you get then (there could be other issues after you fix this one).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I had passed as Filesystem as you suggested - able to run the lambda successfully - But still give the above output with no value. :(

Comment: ` 'Dimensions': [
                           {
                               'Name': 'InstanceId',
                               'Value': 'i-******'
                           },
                           {
                               'Name': 'Filesystem',
                               'Value': '/***/***'
                           },
                           {
                               'Name': 'MountPath',
                               'Value': '/'
                               
                           },
                       ]
`

Comment: Double check the namespace, metric name and all dimensions. Then try removing the unit. Check that the lambda function is in the same region as the metric. If nothing helps, graph the metric in CloudWatch Dashboards, open the Source tab on the graph and update your answer with the source (just remove the parts you don't want public, like you did before).

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't helped much. Tried changing Namespace, Dimensions and others (tried with other possibilities) as well. Here's the source,

{
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "stacked": false,
    "metrics": [
        [ "CWAgent", "disk_used", "path", "/", "InstanceId", "*******", "ImageId", "********", "InstanceType", "t2.micro", "device", "xvda1", "fstype", "xfs" ]
    ],
    "region": "eu-west-1"
}

Comment: From your source: namespace is `CWAgent`, metric name is `disk_used` and you need to set all of these for dimension name/value: `"path", "/", "InstanceId", "*******", "ImageId", "********", "InstanceType", "t2.micro", "device", "xvda1", "fstype", "xfs" `

Comment: Tried with the changes, but stuck at startTime and endTime. Sorry about this - but I am completely new to this. Just trying to catch up. Below is the code. Can you help me in fixing that?

Comment: ```#from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
   response = client.get_metric_data(

       MetricDataQueries=[
           {
               'Id': 'd1',
               'MetricStat': {
                   'Metric': {
                       'Namespace': 'CWAgent',
                       'MetricName': 'disk_used',```

Comment: ```'Dimensions': [
                           {
                               'Name': 'InstanceId',
                               'Value': 'i-***********'
                           },
                           {
                               'Name': 'device',
                               'Value': 'xvda1'
                           },
                           {
                               'Name': 'path',
                               'Value': '/'
                           },```

Comment: ```  {
                               'Name': 'ImageId',
                               'Value': 'ami-****************'
                           },
                           {
                               'Name': 'InstanceType',
                               'Value':'t2.micro'
                           },
                           {
                               'Name': 'fstype',
                               'Value': 'xfs'
                           },
                       ]
                   },```

Comment: ``` 'Period': 300,
                   'Stat': 'Maximum'
               },
               'ReturnData': True
           },
       ],
       StartTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=600),
       EndTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
       ScanBy='TimestampDescending',
       MaxDatapoints=60
   )
   return response```

Comment: Error which I am getting - Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 25, 16, 56, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError"
}

Comment: Thanks much for your support. Please help me on this

Comment: The error you're getting is coming from lambda because you're trying to return the `response` directly. Try logging the response first and just return an empty string `""` to make sure you get the expected data from CloudWatch. Then you can work on constructing the lambda return object. And please update your question with new things you tried, don't put it in the comments.